# Updating gem paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

If I do a

> which psql

and am seeign the path as, "usr/bin/psql" It needs to be "usr/local/bin/psql"

How do I update the path? I have tried a few other stack overflow threads, but nothing seems to be working for me. I'm using a Mac with Lion. ...the error I'm getting is,

> rake aborted!
>   could not connect to server: Permission denied
>   Is the server running locally and accepting
>   connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

in your in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

see [this superuser.com question](https://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are) for more